# One of the sub menu not properly aligned

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.Net Core project including MVC. My view is completely in HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap. It's so so strange that one of my sub-menu is coming right align, even the CSS, HTML are same for all sub-menu. I tried all possibilities, could not figure out.

[image: Sub menu]

My code is like,

```
 <li>
    <a class="homer" href="#">PRODUCTS & SERVICES</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a title="Repair Shop Management System" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  Repair Management System</a></li>
      <li><a title="RailcarRx Insight" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  RailcarRx Insight</a></li>
      <li><a title="CRB System" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>   CRB System</a></li>
      <li><a title="Integration and Custom Services" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  Integration and Custom Services</a></li>
      <li><a title="RailcarRx Insight" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>  RailcarRx Analytics</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

My CSS for menu is,

```
 nav .menu li > ul.sub-menu li{
 text-transform: none;
 color: #b7b7b7;
 font-size: 12px;
 }
 nav .menu li > ul.sub-menu li {
 z-index: 50005;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0);
 }
 #navigation ul ul li {
 float: none;
 }
 nav .menu li ul.sub-menu li a {
 float: left;
 padding: 7px 0px;
 }
 nav .menu li ul.sub-menu li a:hover{
 color:#cc3300 !important;
 }
 #navigation ul ul ul {
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 }

#navigation ul ul ul:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 10px;
height: 100%;
left: -10px;
top: 0;
opacity: 0;
}
#navigation ul ul:before {
content: "123";
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 10px;
top: -10px;
opacity: 0;
}
#navigation ul li:hover > ul {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

If I change the text or add a letter or space to my sub-menu **CRB System**, it's coming as expected. For example `aCRB System` or `My Sub Menu` etc etc. If I keep `CRB System` sub-menu in other place apart from this 3rd place, it's coming as expected.
So strange!

Any help would be appreciated, why it's coming like this.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle ?

Comment: Can you trie giving `text-align: left;width:100%;display:inline-block` to the `.sub-menu li a` .?

Comment: that was strange may you post the css link? probably due to other css

Comment: @JithinRajPR Not working bro. Could not understand rest are coming properly except this. If I change the text then it's coming properly. It's like so strange.

Comment: @BasantaMatia I have to check the CSS bro. Can you give us a **live link** or just post the CSS here and check if it's working fine(if it is then that is an issue with another style on your page.)

Comment: I added my CSS for menu. Plz check it. Sorry I could not provide a fiddle due to very huge and messy code.

Comment: @BasantaMatia you `code` is not a problem can you give me a live link to the website. So we i can check.?